# Change and reload UITableView with URL input

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've written a simple RSSReader with UITableView. I can make a specified feed display by implementing UITableDataSource in my ViewController class. However, I'm trying to display a feed that is entered into a text box. I've used NSLogs to debug, and the entered feed is properly parsed upon button press. However, upon `[[self tableOfFeeds] reload]` the view is not updated.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setNf: [[NewsFeed alloc] init]];
    if ([textFieldUserInput.text length] == 0)
    link = @"http://afeedurl.com/feed.rss";
     [self.nf setFeedUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];
    [self.nf retrieveFromInternet];
    for (id newsItem in [self.nf newsStories]){ // Debug
        NSDictionary * d = (NSDictionary *) newsItem;
        NSLog(@"Title: %@ \n %@", [d objectForKey:@"title"], [d objectForKey:@"description"]);
    }
    [[self tableOfFeeds] setDataSource:self];
    [[self tableOfFeeds] setRowHeight:70.0];
    [[self tableOfFeeds] reloadData];
}
```

And here's the action that changes the feed.

```
- (IBAction)refreshFeed:(id)sender {
    NSString * ui = self.textFieldUserInput.text;
    if ([ui length] == 0) // If text field is blank, then reload the old feed from internet.
        [[self tableOfFeeds] reloadData];
    else {
        [self.nf setFeedUrl: [NSURL URLWithString:ui]];
        [self.nf retrieveFromInternet];
        [[self tableOfFeeds] setDataSource: self];
        [[self tableOfFeeds] reloadData];

        for (id newsItem in [self.nf newsStories]){ // Debug
            NSDictionary * d = (NSDictionary *) newsItem;
            NSLog(@"Title: %@ \n %@", [d objectForKey:@"title"], [d objectForKey:@"description"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting up a few break points and stepping through cellForIndexPath: would be a good port of call in tracing the root cause of the lack of table update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code in the question seems to be valid. I traced the issue to this method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString * cellId = @"feeds";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellId];
        NSMutableDictionary * news = (NSMutableDictionary *) [[[self nf] newsStories] objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
        [[cell textLabel] setText: [news objectForKey:@"title"]];
        [[cell detailTextLabel] setText: [news objectForKey:@"description"]];
        [[cell detailTextLabel] setNumberOfLines:2];

    }
        return cell;
}
```

The part that declares the NSMutable Dictionary and sets the cell text needs to be out of the if statement.

I think this works because most of the cells I'd like to change already contain data, and therefore alloc/init doesn't need to be called.